# How to fill in missing values based on some condition?

Tags: r

I want to convert df to df1 by filling some NA with last observation carried forward. Below is my example dataframe df:

```
df <-read.table(textConnection("
a        b
NA      NA
NA      NA
NA      NA
515     NA
513     NA
615     50
NA      58
NA      62
250     51
154     NA
42      NA
NA      NA
NA      40
NA      42
NA      30
NA      28
NA      NA
NA      NA
"),header=T)
```

to be converted to df1 like the following:

```
df1 <-read.table(textConnection("
a        b
NA      NA
NA      NA
NA      NA
515     NA
513     NA
615     50
615     58
615     62
250     51
154     51
42      51
NA      51
NA      40
NA      42
NA      30
NA      28
NA      NA
NA      NA
"),header=T)
```

while keeping the heading NA and tailing NA intact. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(zoo)
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {
         x1 <- cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(is.na(x)))))
         indx <- !x1 %in% c(x1[1], x1[length(x1)])
         x[indx] <-na.locf(x[indx])
          x})

identical(df,df1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or using the original `df`

```
df[] <- na.approx(df, method="constant", na.rm=FALSE)
all.equal(df,df1, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```